# Configuração de servidor windows (wamp) para diferentes aplicações com subdomínios

Tags: servidor, wamp, wampserver

Estou desenvolvendo aplicações PHP/Laravel e preciso configurar um servidor local para acessar diferentes diretórios à partir do mesmo domínio, como nos exemplos abaixo:

dominio.com/aplicacao01 --> Acessa uma aplicação x

dominio.com/aplicacao02 --> Acessa uma aplicação y

Como não tenho experiência com configuração de servidor windows nem liberdade para configurar como achar mais adequado, preciso me adaptar ao que foi fornecido:

Servidor windows, rodando o wamp com diferentes diretórios para cada aplicação laravel.

Alguma luz?

Comment: opa, estou usando o wamp também, pega a pasta do seu projeto(aplicação) e coloca dentro da pasta "WWW" dentro da pasta do wamp server, ela está localizada no disco local C:\wamp64\www coloque a pasta ai dentro, depois vc vai no navegador e digita:
localhost/sua_pasta/sua_aplicação.php

Comment: Foi fechada, mas vale o comentário para, caso alguém precise, saiba por onde ir. 
Configurei alias no apache, no .htaccess dentro de public inseri a linha RewriteBase /aplicacao01 abaixo de RewriteEngine On e no .env APP_URL=http://localhost/aplicacao01